# How to get namespace names in XPath?

Tags: xpath, exist-db

I have this .xml file

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
      xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

 <f:table>
  <f:tr>
    <f:td>Red</f:td>
    <f:td>Yellow</f:td>
  </f:tr>
</f:table>

</root>
```

How can i get only the elements with a specify namespace?
For example i want to retrieve only that elements in 'h' namespace.
How can i get it? In exist-db the 'namespace::' axis is not more working

Comment: I solved now so:

    //*[substring-before(./name(),":")='h']

Comment: There is a far better way to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [in-scope-prefixes()](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn%3ain-scope-prefixes?print=yes) function in a predicate:

`//*[in-scope-prefixes(.)='h']`

Comment: I'm surprised `in-scope-prefixes()` didn't work for you, but I'm glad you found a solution. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you show a solution that parses the return value from `name()`:

```
//*[substring-before(name(), ":")='h']
```

There is a **far simpler** way to get all elements in the namespace that's mapped to the `h` prefix:

```
//h:*
```

Note: when I first tested this, I was getting back *all* elements in the document. That's because both of your prefixes are mapped to the *same* namespace:

```
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
```

You should also fix this.